# Meaning of a mathematical model

Tags: finance, mathematical-modeling

There is a statement which said "Plan B can be invested in a period in the multiple of two years". What does this statement mean?

i) the people can invest the money on this plan in first two years, but not the next two years and then again can invest for the another two years...

ii) the people can invest the money on this plan in first year, but not in second year, then he can again invest in third year, and so on...

which one is the explanation for this statement of mathematical model?
Note: this is a multi-period financing problem

Comment: @Moo so the explanation (ii) is the proper one?

Comment: I read it as "Plan B can be invested in a period of 2yrs, 4yrs, 6yrs, 8yrs..." But I don't know anything about financing problems.